# Still getting dividends if shares are sold after ex-div?

Tags: stocks, investing, dividends, ex-dividend-date

Bought some stock in let's call it XXX company about ~2 months before their ex-div date. Sold this stock completely 2 weeks after their ex-div date.

Dividend payment date is next week - do I still get the dividends for the number of shares owned before ex-div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the dividends if you owned the shares *on* the ex-div date. Since you bought them before and sold them after, yes you should get the dividends.

Note that the price of your stock should have dropped roughly by the amount of the dividend (modulo any market fluctuations) on the ex-div date, so your dividend will just be making up for that loss in value.

Comment: Thanks. In this particular case, I bought the stock before ex-div, during the March'20 dip, at a lower value, sold inflated 2 weeks after ex-div in June'20. Possibly buying back into the same position again depending on where the market is going over the next period.